# Send an image file using sockets , Android to Python

Tags: python, android, sockets, file

Im trying to send an image from an android client to a python server , I have achieved it before with a python test client and the server. Basically my client app takes a form consisting of users details and an image. Once the user selects the image I get the uri in the onActivityResult method and parse it to a string Like so

`selectedImagePath = selectedImageUri.toString();`

when the user hits submit button on the form the sending activity is invoked with the form data as extras in an array in a bundle like so.

`Bundle b=new Bundle();
 b.putStringArray("regValues", new String[]{name,email,selectedImagePath});`

in  the sending activity I establish a connection with the server and attempt to send the image like so .

` 
//establish link with the server

```
    try{

     //refer to the host computer's loopback interface
     host = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2"); 
     link = new Socket(host,port);
     in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.getInputStream()));

     //access the strings that were passed to this activity 
     Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
     String[] regFormValues = b.getStringArray("regValues");

     //display connection confirmation

     String message = in.readLine();
     status.setText(message);



        File myFile = new File (regFormValues[2]);
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        OutputStream os = link.getOutputStream();

        os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        link.close();





    }
    catch(IOException e ){

     e.printStackTrace();

    }
    `
```

It connects to the server no problem , the
 server creates a file for output to write the data to as usual but it just appears empty so no data is being recieved. I think it may be a problem with the file path on the client side. Any Ideas ?

EDIT: Basically I would like to know if I am accessing the image file in the right way or if you have any better suggestions for accessing and sending it.

Comment: I doesn't seem so,  I receive the Connected to server message on the client so I know it gets that far , I just get an empty file on the server side , the server has worked before using a python client sending and receiving the image. I think its got to do with the file in the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it , as I `use selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);` to get the uri if its taken by the camera and `selectedImageUri = data.getData();` if its been selected by the file browser. I used `selectedImagePath = selectedImagePath.substring(7);` to strip the file:// form the camera's image path, resulting in a /sdcard/etc or wherever it stored it. To get the file path for the image chosen by the file browser i used this

```
// convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file  
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {  

    // can post image  
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};  
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,  
            proj, // Which columns to return  
            null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)  
            null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)  
            null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)  
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);  
    cursor.moveToFirst();  

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
```

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using methods such as File.exists() and File.isFile() to validate if the path is OK and whether the image is really there

Also check if the image even hits the wire - using tcpdump ro wireshark

Comment: Both  File.exists() and File.isFile() confirm that it does not see the file. the file does exist so it must be how I am accessing it. The way I am currently trying is selecting a file and returning the uri , parsing that to a string and passing the string to the sending activity and trying to open the file there in order to send it. Any suggestions how I could go about accessing the file

Comment: you mean "Both File.exists() and File.isFile() confirm that it does  see the file"  I presume you myFile.isFile().  After bis.read do you see the image in mybytearray?

Comment: I do not see os.close() after os.flush() - that is perhaps the reason.

Comment: No they both return false . But I know the files exist because I can see them by browsing the images in the application. I think its due to the fact Im trying to open the file with paths such as this content://media/external/images/media/3 as strings . Should I be using the uri directly  or a content provider .

Comment: OK - use URI -File has a constructor -  File(URI uri)
Constructs a new File using the path of the specified URI.  Once you prepare myFile - check it with exists or isFile.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort I appreciate it , I have tried converting the string back to a uri and using File(uri) already but I keep getting the constructor file (uri) is undefined. I am doing it like so  Uri  temp = Uri.parse(regFormValues[2]);
         File myFile = new File(temp));

Comment: it works if I hardcode the file path eg "/sdcard/Image.jpg" so I need to figure out how to dynamically point to the selected content as the current way does not work

Comment: I guess you used Uri and not URI. It is Java.net.URI that you must use and not android.net.Uri - that explains the undefined constructor!

Comment: I solved it ..see above, Thanks for your help anyway its appreciated